# Apache Debian mod_rewrite enabled but not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am running Apache 2 in a Debian server with the mod_rewrite enabled but the files didn't loaded.

This is my logs:

```
[Thu Dec 11 07:33:00 2014] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /home/example.com/js, referer: http://example.com/forum/
```

The right location when I access http://example.com/forum/ must be /home/example.com/forum/js but I does the wrong thing.

I has turned AllowOverride from None to All but nothing happened.

This is my virtual host config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
 ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
 ServerName example.com
 ServerAlias www.example.com
 DocumentRoot /home/example.com/
 ErrorLog /home/logs/example.com/error.log 
 CustomLog /home/logs/example.com/access.log combined

<Directory "/home/example.com/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```